Linear Regression Model with Newey West Standard Errors and Interaction Terms in R isn't calculating coefficients for all my variables
I'm working of a regression of how income is impacted by the occurrence of natural disasters. After running AC and Heteroskedasticity tests I need to apply NW standard errors to my model.
My model output using stargaze skips the interaction terms associated with the Flood dummy (see regression output at end)
I attempted the model with only the Flood dummy interaction terms and these were all significant. Also when not interacted both terms are significant.
Any help on how to get the coefficients on these would be highly appreciated!
Here is my code:
Fit the model including all lagged disaster dummy variables, the intensity score, and duration dummies
model_pooled_ols_5e <- lm(log_Average_Wage_and_Salary_Income ~ Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Storm + Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Tropical_Cyclone_Storm + Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Wildfire + Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Flood + Intensity_Score + Duration_Under_1_Week_Dummy + Duration_1_to_3_Weeks_Dummy + Duration_1_Month_Dummy + Duration_Over_1_Month_Dummy + Inner_Regional_Dummy + Major_Cities_Dummy + Outer_Regional_Dummy + Remote_Very_Remote_Dummy + Interaction_Storm_Inner_Regional + Interaction_Storm_Major_Cities + Interaction_Storm_Outer_Regional + Interaction_Storm_Remote_Very_Remote + Interaction_Tropical_Cyclone_Inner_Regional + Interaction_Tropical_Cyclone_Major_Cities + Interaction_Tropical_Cyclone_Outer_Regional + Interaction_Tropical_Cyclone_Remote_Very_Remote + Interaction_Wildfire_Inner_Regional + Interaction_Wildfire_Major_Cities + Interaction_Wildfire_Outer_Regional + Interaction_Wildfire_Remote_Very_Remote + Interaction_Flood_Inner_Regional + Interaction_Flood_Major_Cities + Interaction_Flood_Outer_Regional + Interaction_Flood_Remote_Very_Remote + Year, data=Merged_ABS_EMDAT_simple_duplicates_cleaned_v5)
==================================================================================
Dependent variable:
----------------------------------
log_Average_Wage_and_Salary_Income
Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Storm                                 -0.038
(0.036)
Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Tropical_Cyclone_Storm               0.162***
(0.032)
Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Wildfire                              0.017
(0.021)
Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Flood                               -0.099***
(0.024)
Intensity_Score                                               -0.035
(0.065)
Duration_Under_1_Week_Dummy                                 -0.116***
(0.025)
Duration_1_to_3_Weeks_Dummy                                 -0.063***
(0.023)
Duration_1_Month_Dummy                                      -0.086***
(0.020)
Duration_Over_1_Month_Dummy
Inner_Regional_Dummy                                          0.019
(0.045)
Major_Cities_Dummy                                           0.194***
(0.044)
Outer_Regional_Dummy                                          0.008
(0.044)
Remote_Very_Remote_Dummy
Interaction_Storm_Inner_Regional                              -0.038
(0.024)
Interaction_Storm_Major_Cities                              -0.079***
(0.021)
Interaction_Storm_Outer_Regional                             0.076**
(0.037)
Interaction_Storm_Remote_Very_Remote                        -0.158***
(0.048)
Interaction_Tropical_Cyclone_Inner_Regional                  0.180***
(0.042)
Interaction_Tropical_Cyclone_Major_Cities                     0.023
(0.025)
Interaction_Tropical_Cyclone_Outer_Regional                  0.146***
(0.026)
Interaction_Tropical_Cyclone_Remote_Very_Remote              0.319***
(0.069)
Interaction_Wildfire_Inner_Regional                          0.054**
(0.026)
Interaction_Wildfire_Major_Cities                             -0.036
(0.023)
Interaction_Wildfire_Outer_Regional                          0.109***
(0.035)
Interaction_Wildfire_Remote_Very_Remote                     -0.208***
(0.055)
Interaction_Flood_Inner_Regional
Interaction_Flood_Major_Cities
Interaction_Flood_Outer_Regional
Interaction_Flood_Remote_Very_Remote
Year                                                         0.030***
(0.002)
Constant                                                    -49.791***
(3.301)

Note:                                           Newey-West standard errors applied
Observations                                                  1,967
R2                                                            0.533
Adjusted R2                                                   0.527
Residual Std. Error                                     0.169 (df = 1942)
F Statistic                                         92.337*** (df = 24; 1942)
Note:                                                  *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
Subset the correlation matrix to include only the interaction terms and their correlation with all other variables
interaction_terms <- c("Interaction_Flood_Inner_Regional", "Interaction_Flood_Major_Cities", "Interaction_Flood_Outer_Regional", "Interaction_Flood_Remote_Very_Remote")
Extract the relevant part of the correlation matrix
correlation_matrix_interactions <- correlation_matrix_all[interaction_terms, ]
print(correlation_matrix_interactions)
                                 log_Average_Wage_and_Salary_Income Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Storm

Interaction_Flood_Inner_Regional                            -0.18158278                   -0.03057133
Interaction_Flood_Major_Cities                               0.09542833                   -0.05145906
Interaction_Flood_Outer_Regional                            -0.18727074                   -0.02185281
Interaction_Flood_Remote_Very_Remote                        -0.08479981                   -0.01270038
                                 Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Tropical_Cyclone_Storm

Interaction_Flood_Inner_Regional                                        -0.08403034
Interaction_Flood_Major_Cities                                          -0.14144371
Interaction_Flood_Outer_Regional                                        -0.10310793
Interaction_Flood_Remote_Very_Remote                                    -0.03490910
                                 Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Wildfire Lagged1y_Disaster_Dummy_Flood

Interaction_Flood_Inner_Regional                          -0.09474129                    0.04440241
Interaction_Flood_Major_Cities                            -0.11059196                   -0.08919554
Interaction_Flood_Outer_Regional                          -0.12563254                    0.30334249
Interaction_Flood_Remote_Very_Remote                      -0.04422148                    0.09880484
                                 Intensity_Score Duration_Under_1_Week_Dummy

Interaction_Flood_Inner_Regional         -0.13298999                 0.015142296
Interaction_Flood_Major_Cities           -0.36021593                -0.011496344
Interaction_Flood_Outer_Regional         -0.02933677                -0.055770679
Interaction_Flood_Remote_Very_Remote     -0.03530315                 0.006790861
                                 Duration_1_to_3_Weeks_Dummy Duration_1_Month_Dummy

Interaction_Flood_Inner_Regional                      0.02727324            0.008551952
Interaction_Flood_Major_Cities                        0.20987979           -0.168472347
Interaction_Flood_Outer_Regional                      0.03265276           -0.035494128
Interaction_Flood_Remote_Very_Remote                 -0.05184300            0.014811205
                                 Duration_Over_1_Month_Dummy Inner_Regional_Dummy

Interaction_Flood_Inner_Regional                     -0.07894394           0.70226950
Interaction_Flood_Major_Cities                       -0.15504594          -0.22967180
Interaction_Flood_Outer_Regional                      0.06066184          -0.16742337
Interaction_Flood_Remote_Very_Remote                  0.06464149          -0.05668429
                                 Major_Cities_Dummy Outer_Regional_Dummy Remote_Very_Remote_Dummy

Interaction_Flood_Inner_Regional             -0.3672568          -0.16640793              -0.05299021
Interaction_Flood_Major_Cities                0.4391790          -0.28010542              -0.08919554
Interaction_Flood_Outer_Regional             -0.4506359           0.70655484              -0.06502069
Interaction_Flood_Remote_Very_Remote         -0.1525711          -0.06913159               0.75122639
                                 Interaction_Storm_Inner_Regional Interaction_Storm_Major_Cities

Interaction_Flood_Inner_Regional                          -0.04402616                    -0.12742112
Interaction_Flood_Major_Cities                            -0.07410684                    -0.21448105
Interaction_Flood_Outer_Regional                          -0.05402151                    -

I guess this a variant of this issue: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/639351/missing-coefficients-in-linear-regression-with-multiple-categorical-variables-in Why are you doing the dummy encoding manually?

Without a minimal working example it is very difficult to give an answer, but I suspect that what is happening is that you are referring to categorical variables and for these one of the level of those variables is absent. If that is the case, then this is normal/expected behaviour - the "missing" estimates form part of the intercept. Check out the package emmeans
Here is an example of this in action:
library(ggplot2)
library(emmeans)

set.seed(123)

# Number of observations per group
n <- 30

# Create the 'colour' factor variable
colour <- factor(rep(c("Red", "Green", "Blue"), each = n))

# Simulate the response variable 'value' with different means for each group
value <- c(rnorm(n, mean = 5, sd = 1),   # Red
           rnorm(n, mean = 6, sd = 1),   # Green
           rnorm(n, mean = 7, sd = 1))   # Blue

data <- data.frame(colour, value)

So, we have created a dataset with one independent variable "colour", having 3 levels, Red, Green and Blue. First, we plot the data to visualize the differences (it's always a good idea to visualise your data)
ggplot(data, aes(x = colour, y = value, fill = colour)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(title = "Boxplot of Simulated Data by Colour",
       x = "Colour",
       y = "Value") +
  theme_minimal()


And now we fit the model:
m0 <- lm(value ~ colour, data = data)
summary(m0)

which produces:
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   7.0244     0.1639  42.869  < 2e-16 ***
colourGreen  -0.8461     0.2317  -3.651 0.000445 ***
colourRed    -2.0715     0.2317  -8.939 5.98e-14 ***


...and we see that the estimate for Blue is missing.
Now we estimate marginal means:
em_means <- emmeans(m0, ~ colour)
summary(em_means)

which gives us:
 colour emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 Blue     7.02 0.164 87     6.70     7.35
 Green    6.18 0.164 87     5.85     6.50
 Red      4.95 0.164 87     4.63     5.28

which recovers the "missing" estimate for Blue

@Lucy does this answer your question ? If so please mark it as the accepted answer, and please consider giving an upvote.
